# how to glue the broken plastic pieces that dovetails the faucet valve

Tags: faucet, valve, adhesive, plastic

The faucet handler in my kitchen fell off. I open it found that the plastic piece that dovetails the valve was broken (see the image)

[image]

I am not sure if I can find a replacement of such a thing as I don't even know the brand/model of the faucet. To me there are 2 options though:

1. find a brand of glue that can put the broken two pieces together
2. Use heat (from a lighter) to melt the plastic so they might slightly "melt" into one piece.

I am leaning toward option#1, since #2 might deform the part. So the question is, can anyone suggest a glue that really works in this situation? Or is there any other options?

I am not sure if this of much help, but I'm attaching two more images of the faucet.[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should look with great care and bright light for some indication of a brand name somewhere on the faucet. Because a replacement part is really the only viable solution (short of replacing the whole faucet.)

1: Plastic glues are almost always not as strong as the original part. **IF** the plastic is a solvent-weldable plastic and **IF** you have the correct solvent, you have the possible exception, **if** you do a good job solvent-welding it.

2: The original part broke, probably in part due to the plastic aging poorly - so if you do successfully glue it, it will probably break again, either in the same spot or a new spot.

Another option, depending how difficult it is to model, would be to have a new part 3D printed. But if you can buy a replacement (which starts with sorting out who made the faucet) that will be considerably less effort (unless you have someone that's dying to work cheap to show off what their 3D printer can do.)

Comment: Thank you sir. I might just follow your suggestion to look up for the manufacturer

Comment: You might want to wait a few days on the "acceptance" (green check-mark) - some people are less prone to answer when another answer has been accepted, and someone might have a better answer to contribute.

Comment: Some faucet manufacturers will send you parts for free (long warranties) by calling the customer service number.  In the past I've actually received an entire replacement faucet at no charge when the first part they sent didn't fit.

Comment: My experience is similar to Tyson's.  Moen has a lifetime guarantee.  They've sent a number of replacement components on long-obsolete faucets (free).  If you can't find a manufacturer name anywhere on the faucet, look online at the major manufacturer web sites to see if you can identify it.  You can even send a picture of it to customer service at the companies to see if they can identify it as theirs.  Once you have the manufacturer, identifying the part is easy.

Comment: Yes, getting a replacement part (possibly even a re-engineered, better, replacement part) for free is obviously better than buying one.